# Ruby time.new vs time.now

Tags: ruby

[testfirst.org Performance Monitor rspec](http://testfirst.org/live/learn_ruby/performance_monitor)

I'm working on the above problem provided by testfirst.org. Below is my code and all tests pass:

```
def measure(iterate = 1)
  timestamp = Time.now
  iterate.times { yield }
  timestamp_end = Time.now
  (timestamp_end - timestamp) / iterate
end
```

However, if I replace `Time.now` with `Time.new`, some of the tests fail. I read that Time.now is an alias of Time.new. So why do the tests fail and what is the difference created from using both methods?

Comment: @Makoto: I'm currently running Ruby version 2.2.1, and unfortunately, the tests still fail. Even running my code using `Time.new` on the testfirst.org link I posted shows fails as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because the test case [stubs](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/2-3/docs/method-stubs) the return value for `.now` and not `.new`:

```
Time.stub(:now) { @eleven_am }
```

Since the tests expect `@eleven_am` as the return value, they fail. You'd have to stub `Time.new`, but who knows what other havoc that might wreck.